# How to make an event when there is a refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, browser-refresh

I'm making a web-quiz, there are the users logged in this game and they have to reply to a quiz with 3 alternatives, the problem comes when the user is a bit clever because if he does a refresh all the question change so the user can do this until he find the one that he knows, how can I put in my website (after an alert) wrong question?
example:

1. USA is in EU
2. UK is in Africa
3. France is in EU

If the users does a refresh, how can I show message such as `alert("if you refresh is a game over")` and save the answer as incorrect in the database?

Comment: Well, a refresh (or any other type of page leaving and loading again) happens when he is requesting your ressource without having answered his current question. That is what you actually want to detect, and you should do that serverside.

Comment: What about legitimate refresh requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest assigning the question in PHP and storing which question you asked in a `$_SESSION` variable. That way when they refresh the page you can show them the same question until they answer it.

**UPDATE**

There is a caveat to this, if your user really is a smarty, they can delete their cookies and refresh the page, which would create a new session for them since session identifiers are saved as a cookie in PHP (by default).